# How to reduce time taken by System.out.println();

Tags: java, performance, io

I am inserting 2_000_000 long values in a list. Each time i insert, i need to print the size of the list to console using SOP. If i do not print size to console the insert finishes in 250 ms. If i print size each time i insert a value then time taken is 25000 ms.

Any idea how can i fix this performance issue?

I am using Java7 and Eclipse (kepler) to test my implementation.

Note: Printing the size each time i insert a long value is required and mandatory by the problem definition.

Comment: Your issue is that you're submitting so many print requests to the console. It would be much faster to build up a string of all the list lengths and submit it at the end.

Comment: If it is a requirement to print each time and this implies a visible result in the console/process output, there is nothing you can do. All solutions suggesting buffering imply that the messages will be seen at a later time. Of course, a human reader won’t notice the delay when the total execution time is 250ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html). It allows efficient character writing.
Also, don't forget to call the [flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush--) method in the end so that all buffered data is outputted.

Working example:

```
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))) {
        for(long i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
            bw.write("Current size:" + list.size());
            bw.newLine();
            if(i % 100 == 0 || i == 1999999) {
                bw.flush();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A second option could be using a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    int initialCapacity = 200000;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(initialCapacity);
    for (long i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
        list.add(i);
        sb.append("Current size:").append(list.size()).append(separator);
        if (i % 10000 == 0 || i == 1999999) {
            System.out.println(sb);
            sb = new StringBuilder(initialCapacity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And…is the second solution still slower than the first?

Comment: No, the second solution is faster now (roughly by 20% on my computer).

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
for (long myLong : values)
{
    list.add(myLong);
    writer.write(list.size());
}
```

Once you're completely done, or perhaps every 1000 inserts, call

```
writer.flush();
```